# Limiting app for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I created an iPad app and want to submit it.

Is there anything extra I need to do to set the device kind to iPad or is it set automatically?

What Target sdk should it be set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the "**Targeted device Family**" in your project settings.

Here is the description :

> The build system uses the selected
>   device to set the correct value for
>   the UIDeviceFamily key it adds to the
>   target's Info.plist file.
>   [TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY]
>
> iPhone - Application is built for
>   iPhone and iPod touch. iPad -
>   Application is built for iPad.
>   iPhone/iPad - Application is built
>   Universal for iPhone, iPod touch, and
>   iPad.

Comment: Cool. What is a good iOS to choose for Ipad as a deployment version?

Comment: I think minimum iPad OS is 3.2

Answer (score 1):

In general the:

- "Base SDK" should always be set to the most recent, there's really no reason to build with an older SDK
- "iOS Deployment Target" should be set to the *earliest* OS version you want the app to run on, and
- "Targeted Device Family" should be set to "iPad", "iPhone", or "iPhone/iPad" (the last for a universal app)

Comment: I know thanks. Wondered what was a good choice for the ipads deployment target.

Comment: earliest possible iOS supporting iPad is 3.2